# main.cpp|15|error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]| error when making a game

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm making an rpg.
When i enter the code(shown below)
i get this error.
What am i doing wrong?

main.cpp|15|error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int mainLoop()
{
    char arr[4] = {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'};
    int pp = 1;
    bool end = false;
    string inp;

    arr[pp] = "S";

    while(end == false)
    {
        cout << arr << endl;
        cout << ">>: " << endl;
        cin >> inp;

        if(inp == "move")
        {
            pp++;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    mainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks! but now i have it leaving the old pp(player position) as S.
I have tried making a new variable ppold and making it change pp-1 to x but nothing happens.

Comment: Man, listen to my advise: first learn to code, then start making games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr[pp] = "S";  //incorrect
```

should be

```
arr[pp] = 'S';  //correct
```

The type of `"S"` is `char[2]` which is not convertible to `char` which is the type of `arr[pp]`.  But the type of `'S'` is `char` which matches with the type of `arr[pp]` (which is `char` also).

Answer (score 2):

`"S"` (double quotation mark) means it is a null terminated string, which is `{'S', '\0'}` when expanded.

`'S'` (single quotation mark) means it is a char character, which is `{'S'}` when expanded.

arr[X] is a character in a character array in your example (think of it as a single quotation expression, like 'a')

You cannot assign `{'S', '\0'}` to `{'a'}`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c) is more information about the situation.