# What's causing error "Cannot convert 'unsigned char'"?

Tags: c

My function transforms hex symbol into string of 2 characters, then breaks it into 2 strings of 1 characters. When I compare resulted string with constant string, I get an error: `Cannot convert 'unsigned char'  to 'char *' first_ascii_code = 0x30;`

compiler: C++ Builder 6

code:

```
BYTE from_byte_to_ascii_codes(int input_byte);
// transformation hex into string with of 2 characters and then 
// its transformation into 2 hex bytes. compiler - C++ Builder 6

BYTE from_byte_to_ascii_codes(int input_byte)
{
BYTE broken_input_byte[] = "";
input_byte = 0x01;
itoa(input_byte, broken_input_byte, 16);
// now broken_input_byte[] = "01";
if (broken_input_byte[0] == "0") { // here is mistake   
//Cannot convert 'unsigned char'  to 'char *'
first_ascii_code = 0x30;
}
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Did you enable all warnings with your compiler? Did you use the debugger? You should learn to use it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: you cannot compare string `broken_input_byte[0] == "0"` like this.. use strcmp()

Answer (score 3):

The test `broken_input_byte[0] == "0"` is incorrect. You probably want to test if the first character is the `'0'` char, so you should code `broken_input_byte[0] == '0'` (assuming `BYTE`, an implementation specific name, is `typedef`-ed to `char`).

In C, any test like `foo == "string"` is certainly wrong; it is an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because `"string"` is in fact the *address* of some constant string literal data, so such a test would compare the pointer `foo` to some constant pointer (and even `"aa" == "aa"` could be false, because the compiler might build two constant strings `"aa"` located at different addresses!). BTW, with a recent GCC compiler you get a warning (when compiling with `gcc -Wall`) on it.

You probably want to use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) to compare null-terminated strings.

Comment: It is not undefined behavior to compare two arbitrary pointers for equality, though as you say, it is wrong here.  I would also mention that `broken_input_string` is not a large enough buffer to hold the result of the call to `itoa`.

Comment: But it is UB to compare a pointer against a constant literal string.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I missed that.  I believe it's unspecified behavior though, not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`"0"` is a string not character in `C` while `broken_input_byte[0]` is a `BYTE` equivalent to `char` in `C`, so both are not same type hence the error.

If you want to compare strings `strcmp` is the function not `==` operator.

Comment: thanx for help. I unterstood how do it more simply, without strings