# Array sum is giving the wrong answer when the program is ran

Tags: c++

The program runs smoothly and I have no errors or warnings when its compiled its just when it gets the end result I just get a load of random letters and numbers no matter what I put in.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int hold;
     int n;
     int * result = new int;
     int * price = new int;
     std::string items[6];

        for (n=0; n<6; n++)
        {
            cout << "Item#" << n+1 << ": ";
            cin >> items[n];
        }
        cout <<  "\nYou Entered: ";
        for (int n=0; n<6; n++)
            cout << items[n] << ", ";

    for (n=0; n<6; n++)
    {
        if (items[n] == "ab"){
        price[n] = 2650;
        }

        else if (items[n] == "ae"){
        price[n] = 1925;
        }

        else if (items[n] == "ie"){
        price[n] = 3850;
        }

        else if (items[n] == "bt"){
        price[n] = 3000;
        }

        else if (items[n] == "pd"){
        price[n] = 2850;
        }

        else if (items[n] == "ga"){
        price[n] = 2600;
        }

    }

    for (n=0; n<6; n++)
    {
     result += price[n];
    }

    cout << "\nTotal gold for this build: " << result;
    cin >> hold;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `result` is an `int *`. This kind of variable usually stores the address of another integer variable, which you get with `new int` in this specific case. However, with

```
 result += price[n];
```

you'll modify that address, which would lead to segmentation faults if you were to actually write/read from `*result`. This is also the reason why you output is strange:

```
cout << "\nTotal gold for this build: " << result;
```

This prints the adress stored in result, not the value. Make `result` an integer and it should work.

Please note that `price` should be changed too, see [Luchian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874417/1139697).

#### Exercise

1. Change your code so that there is no use of `new`.
2. Your program could still fail. What is the initial value of `result`?
3. What happens if the user provides a code which is not in your list?

Comment: Thanks for the response I'm working on it I'm new to this stuff so I have to read through how to use something if I dont know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

```
int * price = new int;
```

and

```
int * result = new int;
```

allocate a single `int` respectively. You probably meant `new int[6]`.

But then again, you should be using `std::vector` instead.

I'm disappointed really that you took no advice from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12868164/673730 - if you had, you wouldn't have this problem now. This is not a good way to learn.

Comment: Okay I changed 

`int * result = new int;`

to

`int result;` and now I get a number as my result but its still the wrong number it doesnt add up any of the values I have entered in the if statements even if I've used "ae" 6 times for example.

Comment: @user1742497: The real culprit is `result += price[n]`. But there are many other flaws in this code, including those which Luchian already showed.

Answer (score 1):

With this declaration: `int * price = new int;` you only allocate space for a single `int`, but you go on to use `price` as an array of `int`.

To declare an array, use: `int *price = new int[5];`

As for `result`, you declare that as a pointer to `int` also, but you later use it as an `int`: `result += price[n];`. No need to `result` to be a pointer. Also note that you need to initialize your variables explicitly: set `result` to zero before you begin using it.

Answer (score 1):

just give some comments:

1. new operater should be used with delete.
2. "int *result" you declared is a point to int, so you should dereference this point to get the result you want.
3. exceptions should be taken into consideration, what if the input letter is not in your given list?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
cout << "\nTotal gold for this build: " << result;
```

to

```
cout << "\nTotal gold for this build: " << *result;
```

`Result` is a pointer, so you need to dereference it, using the * operator;

**Edit:** Change the declaration of the `price` array to

```
int *price = new int[6];
```

The previous declaration declared a variable, not an array