# How to compare a char in a string to a specific char?

Tags: c++, string, char, string-literals, equality-operator

I was tasked with writing a program in c++11 (though my example and code were made in 14) that takes a user inputted string and tells you how many lowercase vowels there are in the string. However, when I try to compare the ith value in a string to a char, I get an error message telling me that operand types (char and const char) are incompatible. The code for that looked like this:

```
std::string inWord;
int lowerVowels = 0;

std::cin >> inWord;

void searchString(std::string inWord, int& lowerVowels) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inWord.length(); i++) {
        if (inWord.at(i) == "a") {
            std::cout << "lowercase vowel found!";
            lowerVowels++;
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried declaring other strings like so:

```
std::string la = "a", le = "e", li = "i", lo = "o", lu = "u";
```

and made this absolute nightmare of a for loop inside my `searchString` function like this:

```
if (inWord.at(i) == la.at(0) || inWord.at(i) == le.at(0) ||
    inWord.at(i) == li.at(0) || inWord.at(i) == lo.at(0) ||
    inWord.at(i) == lu.at(0)) {
     lowerVowels++;       
}
```

Which worked, however I'm sure I'm missing an easier way here, because this felt ridiculous.
If anyone can explain why the first try didn't work (or because it's kind of easy to assume why that happened) what I should've done instead (unless my solution is considered optimal, which I doubt) I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Just create a `std::set` like `std::set<char> container = {la.at(0). le.at(0). li.at(0)...};` and then do `const bool is_in = container.find(inWord.at(i)) != container.end();`

Comment: Change `""` to `''` in if condition.

Comment: What learning material (books, tutorials, etc.) do you use? What do they say about the difference between `"a"` and `'a'`?

Comment: _"I get an error message telling me that operand types (char and const char) are incompatible"_ - No you don't. Copy/paste the exact error message into the question and you'll see.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was unaware that mattered, would've certainly made this a lot easier. I suppose I had a very subpar professor who didn't offer reading material for computer science 1, and didn't like to show up to his own classes. Kind of playing catch up now, so I appreciate the help. Probably should've caught that by now though, thanks anyhow!

Comment: @calebschwab -- FYI:  You could have used [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count the number of lower case vowels. [See this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3sr1njK7W).  In general, if you want to count the number of <whatever> in a container, `std::count` or `std::count_if` can be used.

Comment: Dupe: [Comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868143/comparison-with-string-literal-results-in-unspecified-behaviour)

Comment: It is simple. Use C and not C++.

Comment: Concerning `inWord.at(i)`: you **know** that `i` is a valid index into `inWord` because you wrote the `for` loop to ensure that. There's no need for the extra stuff that `inWord.at(i)` does; just use `inWord[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `std::set` and use its `find` member or `contains`(in C++20) as shown below:

```
char la = 'a', le = 'e', li = 'i', lo = 'o', lu = 'u';
std::set<char> container = {la, le, li, lo, lu};
//with c++20
const bool is_in = container.contains(inWord.at(i));
if(is_in)
{
}
```

**Pre C++20**

```
//pre c++20
const bool is_in2 = container.find(inWord.at(i)) != container.end();
if(is_in2)
{
}
```

---

Note also that double quotes around like in `"a"` represents a **string literal**. What you actually wanted was a **character literal** which is created using a single quote. This means that you're trying to compare a string literal(`"a"`) which **decays** to a `const char*` to a `char`(`inWord.at(i)`) and hence the error `operand types (char and const char*) are incompatible`

Answer (score 0):

In the expression of this if statement

```
if (inWord.at(i) == "a") {
```

the string literal `"a"` has type `const char[2]`. Used as an operand of the equality operator it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character of the type `const char *`.

On the other hand, the expression `inWord.at(i)` yields an object of the type `char`.

So actually you are trying to compare a character with a pointer that does not make sense.

Instead of the string literal you need to use a character literal like

```
if (inWord.at(i) == 'a') {
```

Nevertheless to count lower case vowels you could use member function `find_first_of` of the class `std::string`. For example

```
const char *vowels = "aeiou";
size_t lowerVowels = 0;

for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
      ( pos = inWord.find_first_of( vowels, pos ) ) != std::string::npos; 
      ++pos )
{
   ++lowerVowels;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    std::string inWord( "Programming" );

    size_t lowerVowels = 0;

    for (std::string::size_type pos = 0;
        ( pos = inWord.find_first_of( vowels, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
        ++pos)
    {
        ++lowerVowels;
    }

    std::cout << lowerVowels << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

The corresponding function can look the following way as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type searchString( const std::string &inWord, const std::string &vowels = "aeiou" )
{
    std::string::size_type lowerVowels = 0;

    for (std::string::size_type pos = 0;
        ( pos = inWord.find_first_of( vowels, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
        ++pos)
    {
        ++lowerVowels;
    }

    return lowerVowels;
}

int main()
{
    std::string inWord( "Programming" );

    std::cout << searchString( inWord ) << '\n';
}
```