# Python - How can I read input from a device using ioctl or spidev?

Tags: python, c, ioctl, spi

I have a [hardware device](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=56131&f=93) and the vendor that supplied it gave a bit of C code to listen for button presses which uses `ioctl`.  The device has an SSD1289 controller.

> Push buttons require no additional pins, their status canbe read over SPI.

That's what I want, to read which push button was pressed.

I am trying to replicate this script in Python for my own application, but the _IOR and ioctl requirements are throwing me off.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#define SSD1289_GET_KEYS _IOR('keys', 1, unsigned char *)

void get_keys(int fd)
{
    unsigned char keys;
    if (ioctl(fd, SSD1289_GET_KEYS, &keys) == -1)
    {
        perror("_apps ioctl get");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Keys : %2x\n", keys);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *file_name = "/dev/fb1";
    int fd;
    fd = open(file_name, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("_apps open");
        return 2;
    }

    while(1)
    get_keys(fd);

    printf("Ioctl Number: (int)%d  (hex)%x\n", SSD1289_GET_KEYS, SSD1289_GET_KEYS);
    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know that Python has an [ioctl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) module, and at some point I should be calling

```
file = open("/dev/fb1")
buf = array.array('h', [0])
fcntl.ioctl(file,  ????, buf, 1)
```

I can't figure out what the `SSD1289_GET_KEYS` is supposed to be.  How do I get this and what is `_IOR`?

Also, if this is the wrong approach, knowing that would be a help too.  There are libraries such as [spidev](http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf) which are supposedly for SPI, but I don't know what to read using it.

---

@alexis provided some useful steps below, which got me to this point:

```
import fcntl
import array
file = open("/dev/fb1")
buf = array.array('h', [0])
fcntl.ioctl(file, -444763391, buf, 1)
```

Now, pressing a button changes the value of buf if I keep the above in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to figure out the constant to use. Your vendor's program will actually print it out, in decimal and hex-- if you would just edit `main()` and move the `printf` line above the endless `while` loop:

```
printf("Ioctl Number: (int)%d  (hex)%x\n", SSD1289_GET_KEYS, SSD1289_GET_KEYS);

while(1)
    get_keys(fd);
```

Explanation:

`_IOR` is a macro defined in `sys/ioctl.h`. Its definition is as follows:

```
#define _IOC(inout,group,num,len) \
    (inout | ((len & IOCPARM_MASK) << 16) | ((group) << 8) | (num))
#define _IO(g,n)    _IOC(IOC_VOID,  (g), (n), 0)
#define _IOR(g,n,t) _IOC(IOC_OUT,   (g), (n), sizeof(t))
#define _IOW(g,n,t) _IOC(IOC_IN,    (g), (n), sizeof(t))
```

I have included the relevant context lines. You can see that this macro constructs a bit mask that (we can tell from the name) deals with read operations. But your goal is to figure out the bitmask you need, which you can do without too much trouble: Run your vendor's C program through `cc -E`, and you'll see the source after preprocessor commands have applied. Track down the definition of `get_keys` (there'll be a whole lot of header files first, so it'll be at the very end of the output), and pull out the second argument.

The result just might be system-dependent, so you should really try it yourself. On my box, it comes out as

```
((__uint32_t)0x40000000 | ((sizeof(unsigned char *) & 0x1fff) << 16) | ((('keys')) << 8) | ((1)))
```

Not eager to translate that into python, I added the following lines at the very start of `main()`:

```
printf("%d", ((__uint32_t)0x40000000 | ((sizeof(unsigned char *) & 0x1fff) << 16) | 
               ((('keys')) << 8) | ((1))));
exit(0);
```

I ran the program and it gave me the output `1702458113`, which *may* be the value you need. It should be the same as the decimal output from the `printf` command that was already there (but hidden below the endless `while` loop). But check it yourself and don't blame me if you blow out your hardware or something!

Comment: Fantastic, this got me to the right spot!  `cc -E` gave me a different thing but when I put it at the beginning of `main()`, I got -444763391.  Used it and I'm able to read.  Mind you, I don't understand a lot of this but your instructions were clear enough. I will update original post with the code that appears to work for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! As I wrote, the value might be system-dependent. I looked at the code again and added another clue-- the vendor's code actually tries to help, but it doesn't quite work out of the box.

Comment: Would be nice to make it robust - I did find a ['port'](http://www.hsg-kl.de/faecher/inf/material/bonsai/util/ppdev.py) of the `_IOR` macro but it doesn't seem to take 'keys'.

Comment: The vendor's code is playing non-standard C type games; `'keys'` is treated as an array of 4 bytes,  equivalent to a 64-bit int (big-endian, I guess). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3684046/699305). (I used `clang`, which apparently doesn't support this). You could replicate the calculation in python, but since all you need is that one int, why bother?

Comment: Cool, yep it's good enough.  I'll post this as a curiosity question later on.