# Scanf() working differently with \n and '\n' supplied in format specifier

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
    float longi;
    float lati;
    char info[80];
    int started = 0;

    puts("Data=[");
    while((scanf("%f\n%f\n%s",&lati,&longi,info))==3){ //here is my doubt.


        printf("\n{latitude:%f, longitude:%f, info:%s},",lati, longi, info);
    }
    puts("\n]");    
}
```

The above code works as desired, but I figured it out by trial and error. This takes three inputs with the 'enter' key as separator.  Initially I supplied:

`'\n'`  instead of `\n`

in the format specifier, but that was of no use; it was taking only one input every time.

What's the difference between these two and how does `scanf()` handle them?

Comment: So you had a `scanf("%f'\n'%f'\n'%s",&lati,&longi,info)`?

Comment: @favoretti yes but it was not working, \n was working.

Comment: `'` inside the string is a character literal.  This means scanf was expecting to receive the `'` character on the input.  I anticipate that you didn't intend to supply one.

Comment: @AlexBrown yes i think, i will test it by supplying '\n' after giving each input except last.

Comment: Why not just have `scanf("%f%f%s",&lati,&longi,info)` What is your worry with this?

Comment: @Gopi : it will not work, your code is not working, i have to supply spaces but i require that user press enter each time for entering the data input

Comment: @AlexBrown :( its not working, but why?

Comment: @Rouftantical What is not working I don't get why is `\n` needed in scanf() the format specifers will take care

Comment: @Gopi please check it by running

Comment: [check this](http://ideone.com/wjstNb)

Comment: @Gopi yes it works but i need that user press enter

Comment: @Rouftantical Who is pressing enter here ?? I am the user who is pressing the enter. scanf() is well defined why do you need `\n` in `scanf()` totally not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you had a `scanf("%f'\n'%f'\n'%s",&lati,&longi,info)` in your code.

When you break this code up:

- `%f` - expect a float
- `'` - expect a literal `'` in the input
- `\n` - expect a line break
- `'` - expect a literal `'` in the input

... and so on.

`\n` is a linebreak. Unquoted. 
The reason that some manuals show it in single quotes is a difference between a `char` that's represented by two symbols in code and a string literal.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c) for more explanation.

Proper code is the one you already stated yourself:

`scanf("%f\n%f\n%s",&lati,&longi,info)`

Comment: `\n` matches any sequence of white space (and is redundant here). To match a literal newline, `%*1[\n]` is needed