# What's the difference between " and '?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equality

Why does my code work, when I use " in the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(grid[row][i]!=0){
            if(player == "yellow"){
                grid[row][i-1] = 'y';
            }
            else if(player == "red"){
                grid[row][i-1] = 'r';
            }
        }
    }
```

But don't work, when I use ' in the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(grid[row][i]!=0){
            if(player == 'yellow'){
                grid[row][i-1] = 'y';
            }
            else if(player == 'red'){
                grid[row][i-1] = 'r';
            }
        }
    }
```

It is always saying, "Invalid character constant". 
  - grid is a 2 dimensional char variable 
  - row is an interger 
  - player is the super class (window) protected and in the constructor of the super    class occupied with the value yellow:

```
protected String player;

public window() {
    player = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: "" is for Strings, '' is for chars.

Comment: Always compare String objects using the equals method

Comment: This might explain it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: *Why does my code work, when I use " in the following code* when you use double quotes your code *compiles* but **it won't work as expected** because `String`s are compared using `equals` method, not `==`. For more info on this, check [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1065197)

Comment: Darn, I was typing up a neat answer and the question got closed.

Comment: @DTH please provide answers based on the specific programming language OP asks. That question belongs to C/C++ and this is Java, they're different (even if the answer may apply for this case).

Comment: Since I can't post an answer, I'm summarizing it in this comment. Basically, a char is a primative data type, while String is an object. This means that String will provide you with some decent methods like `substring()` (there is a Character class, which is a wrapper class of char though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A character is just a single character, such as 'a' or 'b'. A String is one or many characters strung together, like "hello world" or "p". Single quotes(') are used for character literals, while double quotes(") are used for Strings.

Comment: Your initial statement isn't quite right, unless this is an area java differs from C#, a char is a single character, however just because it has a single character doesn't mean it's a char. "a" and 'a' are two different values. "a" is a string with a length of 1 and 'a' is a char value.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you for noticing that.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That helps me understanding Java even better.

Answer (score 3):

In java you use `""` for strings of letters (Strings) and `''` for a single character (Chars)

Example:

- `"The fox jumped"` would be surrounded by double quotes because it has more than one character.
- `'c'` would be surrounded by single quotes because it has only one character.

Be aware that a `String` can be composed by a single or multiple characters, while a `char` consists of a single character.

Comment: Seem my comment on kirbyquerby's answer. The concept of string vs char is a little different than you describe it as.

Comment: I added an edit for it. Thank you.