# Why the control of my PRO*C program doesn't go to the if section?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am beginner in C and PRO*C and need some help. I have a structure as below:

```
typedef struct pt_st{
  char (*s_no)[NULL_BIG_SEQ_NO];
  char (*s)[NULL_STORE];
} pt_st;

pt_st pa_st;
```

Then I have:

```
   EXEC SQL DECLARE c_st CURSOR FOR
   SELECT 5 as s, nvl(null, 0) as s_no
   FROM dual;
```

Then I open and fetch the cursor as below:

```
EXEC SQL OPEN c_st;
EXEC SQL FETCH c_st INTO :pa_st.s, :pa_st.s_no;
```

afterwards, somewhere in my code I have:

```
    if (pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec] == "0") 
    {
        // do something here, but the control of the program never reaches here!!!  
    }
```

But the control of the program never goes iside the if condition.

How can I make this work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Updated based on comments.

`s_no` is a pointers to an array of `char`. ( I missed this earlier)

You are comparing pointer with "0" which is a pointer to a null terminated string. "0" is a string with '0' and a NULL terminator. No warnings here. But incorrect comparison nonetheless.

You are possibly wanting to dereference the `char` pointer at `ll_cur_rec` and see if it equals '0'.

`if ((*pa_st.s_no)[ll_cur_rec] == '0')`

Also, check this : [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c)

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply. I changed it to '0', but still the control doesn't go to the if while it should.

Comment: That means the condition is not being met. `pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec]` is not `0`. Try printing the value of `pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec]`

Comment: You would have got that warning in your previous code with `""`. With `''` you should be fine.

Comment: No, I get it when change the code as you recommended :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78537/discussion-between-prabhu-and-dax).

Comment: I needed the * before array. if (*pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec] == 0)  works as I want to :-)   thank you!

Comment: As written, `s_no` is a *pointer to an array of `char`*, not an array of pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec]` points to a char variable as per the your struct pt_st declaration and when it comes to your comparison in `if` statement you are actually comparing with a string "0". String "0" is actually two characters being '0' followed by '\0' a NULL terminator. Hence your comparison should be with char literals as,

```
if (pa_st.s_no[ll_cur_rec] == '0') { }
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply. I changed it to '0', but still the control doesn't go to the if while it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing.

First of all, you've declared both `s` and `s_no` as *pointers to arrays of `char`*, not arrays of pointer to `char`.  Is that what you intended?  Given that both `5` and the result of `nvl(null,0)` will be integers, why not declare those fields as integers, such as:

```
typedef struct pt_st{
   int s_no
   int s;
} pt_st;
```

then your condition would simply be

```
if ( pt_st.s_no == 0 )
{
  ...
}
```

If you want to store string expressions from the database, declare them as `VARCHAR`:

```
VARCHAR foo[ len ];
```

Note that a `VARCHAR` has two fields - `arr` for storing the string contents, and `len` for storing the string length.

You cannot compare strings in C using the `==` operator.  You must use a library function like `strcmp` or `strncmp`, such as

```
if ( strcmp( str, "0" ) == 0 ) // str is equal to the string "0"
{
  ...
}
```