# C - single quotes vs double quotes

Tags: c, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm curious about this code:

```
int a = 'ftyp';          // a == 1718909296
int b = *((int*)"ftyp"); // b == 1887007846
```

My question: Why a != b ?

Comment: You should first explain why do you assume: a == b .

Comment: It's big endian vs little endian. It becomes more obvious when you use hex: `a` is `0x66747970` and `b` is `0x70797466`.

Comment: thanks a lot. this one is grade help for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
int a = 'ftyp';          // a == 1718909296
```

sets `a` to the multi-character constant, which has implementation defined value. The value of `a` is not defined by the standard. See [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c) for more details.

```
int b = *((int*)"ftyp"); // b == 1887007846
```

is cause for undefined behavior due to violation of [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

The expectation that `a == b` is ill founded.

Comment: No, the problem here is not aliasing. Aliasing only would be a problem if an object that is aliased would be modified. Then the compiler could make a false assumption that the object that it see through a pointer hasn't changed. The real problem here is possible mis-alignment.

Comment: @JensGustedt Is behavior not undefined if you don't use compatible objects.

Comment: @JensGustedt, From C+11 Standard 3.10/10: *If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined*. None of the clauses that follow allow to access the value of a string literal through a `int*`.

Comment: Citing the C spec rather than C++ for a C language issue would be more convincing.  I do not see that the C++ cite supports that is this an aliasing, even thought  it is UB for the aliment issue of [@Jens Gustedt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163949/c-single-quotes-vs-double-quotes#comment63756279_38163972).

Comment: @chux, fair enough. From C99 Standard 6.5/7: *An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
the following types:* More from that section is cited at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/434551.

Comment: Hmmmm, It appears OP's problem is a violation of _strict aliasing_ as it does not meet C11  §6.5 7.  OP's code appears also to violate 3.2 1 alignment: ... objects of a particular type be located on storage boundaries with addresses that are particular multiples of a byte address".  So UB for 2 reasons: aliasing and alignment?

Comment: @chux, I don't think the alignment violation applies here since the OP is not even constructing an object of type `int`.

Comment: OP is attempting to de-reference an `int*` converted from a `char *` with `int b = *((int*)"ftyp")`.  So on systems that allowed that pointer conversion, may still fail the `*(int_pointer)` due to alignment violation.

Comment: @chux, I suspect 3.2/1 controls how members of a `struct` are aligned and padding between such members. I don't think it applies here.