# Printf strange characters

Tags: c

Why it doesn't work? In the end of the program, it shows 2 strange characters instead of "e primo" or "nao e primo". I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // var
    int n, c = 2;
    char p[11];
    // code
    printf("Informe um numero para checar se e primo: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    do {
        if (n % c == 0) {
            p[11] = 'e primo';
            break;
        } else {
            p[11] = 'nao e primo';
        }
        c = c + 1;
    } while (c != n / 2);
    printf("\nO numero %s", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not compile: "too many characters in constant" at the line `p[11] = 'e primo';` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has some problems:

- you cannot copy string with a simple assignment `p[11] = 'e primo';`.  You could use `strcpy()` with a string if you make the buffer larger or you could just use a string pointer `const char *p;`.
- The loop runs forever if `n` is less than `4`.  More precisely, it invokes undefined behavior when `c = c + 1;` causes arithmetic overflow.
- The result is the exact opposite for other values.
- The loop is very slow for large prime numbers, you should stop when `c * c > n`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // var
    int n, c;
    const char *p = "e primo";
    // code
    printf("Informe um numero para checar se e primo: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        for (c = 2; c * c <= n; c = c + 1) {
            if (n % c == 0) {
                p = "nao e primo";
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("O numero %s\n", p);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why when we use char with arrays, we make attributions like:                              C[10] = 'hello'                                                                                                     and when we use pointers we do this:                                                              C = "hello"                                                                                                        why we use '' on the first, and "" on the last?                                                Aren't both strings?

Comment: @Gibas: `C[10] = 'hello'` is a syntax error (or an obsolete multi character character constant which should never be used).  Strings are always surrounded with double quotes `"`.  They can be used to initialize arrays: `char C[10] = "e primo";` or in contexts where they decay into a pointer to their initial character as in pointer initialization: `char *p = "e primo";` and pointer assignments: `p = "nao e primo";`

Comment: I utilized the wrong example, what I meant is that you can't use                      c = "j"                                                                                                                 but you can use                                                                                                                  char C[10] = "e primo"                                                                                         Is it that you need a different notation if it's a single char or a string?

Comment: @Gibas: the syntax with single quotes is for a single character constant, it evaluates to an `int` whose value is the character number in the host encoding: `int c = 'e';`  The syntax with double quotes (`""`) is for character strings which are arrays of `char` with an implicit trailing null terminator (a `char` with the value `0`, conventionally represented as `'\0'`). For example `"abcdef"[2] == 'c'` is true.

Comment: Thank you for answering all my questions!

Answer (score 1):

There's no 12th element in your array; they are only 11 elements in `p`.Your assignments (`p[11] = 'e primo';`) are thus results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`'e primo'` is a multi-byte character literal with implementation-defined behaviour. You probably want to use `strcpy()` to copy.

```
strcpy(p, "e primo");
```

(and increase the array size to accommodate longer string in your other string copy as pointed in the comment).

Or, you can simply use a pointer that point to the string literal as yo don't really need the array.

```
char *p = "nao e primo";
printf("Informe um numero para checar se e primo: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
do {
    if (n % c == 0) {
        p = "e primo";
        break;
    } else {
        p = "nao e primo";
    ...

printf("\nO numero %s", p);
```

Related: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: ... and increase the size of `char p[11];` to accomodate `"nao e primo"`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot say

```
p[11] = 'e primo';
```

p is array of chars, and with p[11] you can set or retrieve the char on 11th position. Secondly, there is no char with index 11. In C, indexing begins from 0, so you can retrieve chars at p[0], p[1], ..., p[10]. 11 elements.

Did you read warnings?

```
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:16:21: warning: character constant too long for its type
             p[11] = 'e primo';
                     ^
1.c:16:21: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
1.c:21:21: warning: character constant too long for its type
             p[11] = 'nao e primo';
                     ^
1.c:21:21: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

It actually says that `character constant too long for its type`.

What you can say:

```
p[10] = 'e'
```

Then, with %s you print "string": array of characters **determined with determinate 0**.
So, after last character that should be visible, you have to say e.g.:
p[10] = '\0'.

I would make the code work, but I am not sure what is actually the point. As it seems, you are always assigning last character to something.

Comment: Strange characters are regarding absence of **'\0'** as the last character. When assigning **char *p = "Some constant string"**, C does this.