# warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, fopen

I have this function to check if a file exists:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int textFileExists(const char *filename){
        FILE *fp=   fopen(filename,'r');
        if(fp==NULL){
            printf("%s %s.\n","There was an error opening ", filename);
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    textFileExists("text.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this code, I get this warning.

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
  FILE *fp= fopen(filename,'r');
```

Running this code gives me a segmentation fault.

What is going on here?

Comment: `'r'` ===> `"r"`

Comment: The second argument of `fopen` should be a string (`char*`) rather than a character (`char`). Change `'r'` to `"r"`. `'r'` is a character while `"r"` is a string literal.

Comment: See: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of literal `'r'` as `fopen` parameter is equivalent to using the following:

```
const char* filename = ...;
char mode = 'r';
fopen(filename, mode);
```

The `'r'` is therefore assumed to be of type `char` and has the value of 0x72 (ASCII). This is then passed to the `char* mode`, converting the 0x72 to a memory address (pointer) to be read from to obtain the characters of `mode` string by `fopen`. Accessing the memory location at 0x72 fails as that location is most probably not available to your application.

For a `char*` literal, you need to use `"r"` as in

```
const char* filename = ...;
const char* mode = "r";
fopen(filename, mode);
```

Answer (score 5):

`'r'` is a single character which, when passed to a function, has type `int`.

The function `fopen()` expects the second argument to be a (`const`) pointer to char (i.e. a `const char *`).   Hence the warning message.  A conversion from an `int` to a pointer is permitted in C, for various reasons, but compilers often treat such conversions as suspicious, and warn you.

The function expects the passed pointer to be a string, which means it assumes the value points to the first character of an array of char.   It doesn't (since you have passed an `int`) so exhibits undefined behaviour.  One symptom of undefined behaviour is a segmentation violation (caused by your operating system detecting your program accessing memory it shouldn't, and sending a `SIGSEGV` signal to your program).

To fix the problem pass `"r"` instead of `'r'`.   Note the double quotes rather than single quotes.   `"r"` is a string literal, which is represented using two characters, `'r'` and `'\0'`, which is what `fopen()` expects.  Doing this will eliminate both the warning and the error when running the program.

Get in the habit of checking warning messages from your compiler BEFORE running the program.   Warnings often indicate a potential problem - in this case, the cause of the warning is also the cause of the abnormal program exit.

Answer (score -2):

In C there's a difference between `'r'` and `"r"`. Check your C book.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but answer should specify where the problem lies, why is it a problem, and what's the solution.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Also not a downvoter, but I think this answer is so terse it’s unlikely to help someone who’s so new they need to ask this question.  Especially since their grasp on pointers, implicit casts, and cstrings is probably rather hazy.  They might fix the error, but not know why the error is fixed.