# Opening files with while loop - C

Tags: c, file, fopen

Hello fellow programmers. 
I have little problem. I cannot figure out how to open files with different numbers (in the filename) going from 1 to whatever number of files exist.

For example, I have two (or eventually *n*) files named `game_1.txt` and `game_2.txt`. This loop should open these two files (or eventually all with this pattern, in that folder).

I am getting errors, namely:

> passing argument 2 of 'fopen' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast.

Here is what I have:

```
main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    int i=1;
    char b;

    while(fr=fopen("game_%d.txt",i) != NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(fr,"%c",&b) > 0)
        {
            printf("%c",b);
        }
        i++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should try to read the man of fopen, the second argument is not for the file numbering (whatever it means) see https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-fopen/ for example

Comment: Sorry, cannot get what do you mean, please explain to fellow starting programmer in simplier words. Many thanks

Comment: the second parameter iis for the mode, I guess it should be "r" in your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407318/warning-passing-argument-2-of-fopen-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast for another example

Comment: Okay, but how else do I make it to open files with %d as variable such as game_1.txt & game_2.txt and else..

Comment: Do not use nor recommend `sprintf`.  use `snprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sprintf()` to build the filename:

```
#include <stdio.h>
                // the c standard requires, that main() returns int
int main(void)  // you should put void in the parameter list if a
{               // when a function takes no parameters.
    char filename_format[] = "game_%d.txt";
    char filename[sizeof(filename_format) + 3];  // for up to 4 digit numbers

    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; ++i) {
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), filename_format, i);
        FILE *fr = fopen(filename, "r");  // open for reading

        if(!fr)      // if the file couldn't be opened
             break;  // break the loop

        int ch;
        while ((ch = fgetc(fr)) != EOF)
            putchar(ch);

        fclose(fr);  // close the file when no longer needed.
    }                // since fr will be overwritten in the next
                     // iteration, this is our last chance.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use nor recommend `sprintf`.  Use `snprintf`.

Comment: @jamesdlin it doesn't really make a difference since the values are limited in this case, but in general you are right, of course, changed.

Answer (score -1):

You may need something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    int i = 1;
    char b;

    while (1) // infinite loop, until broken out of
    {
        char to_open[32];
        snprintf(to_open, 32, "game_%d.txt", i);

        if ((fr = fopen(to_open, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        while (fscanf(fr, "%c", &b) > 0)
        {
            printf("%c",b);
        }

        fclose(fr); // close the file after work is done

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the original code, the API call to [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) would fail, because the second argument it requires is a string, containing the modes that should be used when opening a file (in this case I chose `"r"` - *Open file for input operations*).

The call to [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) into an intermediate temporary array is required, because `fopen` does not support string formatting (such as using `%d`).

Afterwards, the main loop can be finished, when the next file cannot be opened anymore using the `break` statement.

It is also a good idea to include a call to [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/) after the necessary work is done (in this case, the "work" would be the inner `while` loop), so that there are no unnecessary memory and resource leaks.

Comment: What year is this? Why does everyone keep recommending `sprintf`?  Use `snprintf`.  It was standardized almost 20 years ago.