# Reading all files in a directory in C++

Tags: c++, file

Im trying to go through a folder and read all files inside the folder. Reading in one specific file is not a problem, but I cant seem to find a good solution for reading all the files. I have been searching and havent found anything that worked.
So, how would i be able to load all files?
The code that i have now:

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent* lsdir;

dir = opendir("C:\\Users\\Utilizador\\Desktop\\La voz de galicia\\Voz\\Nova pasta");

while ( ( lsdir = readdir(dir) ) != NULL )
{
    printf ("%s\n", lsdir->d_name);
    char tes[260];
    strcpy(tes,lsdir->d_name);
    FILE *f = fopen(tes,"r");
    if(f==NULL){printf("erro");}
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code you've posted? You might find the [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library easier to use

Comment: The file doesnt open im not sure why im guessing that the fopen(tes,"r"); isnt working properly or im not doing it properly

Comment: The name specified by `lsdir->d_name` is *relative* to the path associated with `dir`.  You need to concatenate them to specify the full path.  I'd echo the sentiments of Alan Birtles though: make use of [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) instead.

Comment: Note that `d_name` is a relative path to your starting directory so won't be openable unless your current working directory is the same directory, you need to concatenate the two paths together. You don't need to install anything to use filesystem if you are using a reasonably recent compiler. There's an example in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Comment: You should try something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471134/opening-files-with-while-loop-c/53471288

Comment: @DouglasCunha A Q/A for C is not the best link / hint. C++ meanwhile has something much better in its standard library.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat he is using C in there, for some reason. That's why I posted the C link.