# How to check my char string for spaces?

Tags: c, string, space

I want to take a string and output it without spaces. I wrote the code below but my if statement doesn't seem to detect the spaces in the char string or I am not doing this right.

I assume that my problem is in my if statement but I don't know how to fix it.

```
int main (void)
{
  char s[50];

  printf("Enter string:");
  fgets(s,50,stdin);

  for( int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++ ){
    if( &s[i] != " " ){
     printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter string:xales was here
x
a
l
e
s

w
a
s

h
e
r
e
```

Comment: Replace `if( &s[i] != " " ){` with `if (s[i] != ' ' ){`, the former does not what you probably think.

Comment: `if( &s[i] != " " ){` Comparing an address of a char to a string literal? Works, but never likely to be true... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c

Comment: @yeputons if you write that as an answer il take it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to note is that a double-quoted character is actually a string, not a char type. This value holds a memory address to a place in your program's memory (not a value on the stack) that happens to be 2 bytes long (one for the space, one for `\0`). So that's thing #1: change `"` to `'` and you'll have a single char, on the stack, to compare by value.

Thing number two is that by using the `&` symbol there, you are trying to compare to the address of the `i`th index in your string, instead of the value there. Just remove the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Your if condition is always going to be true, hence, you will be end up printing the entire string as it is.
Your if condition:
    `if( &s[i] != ' ' )  print s [i];`

Here "&" represents address. So in your if block what you are checking is:

```
  ` if(addressof( s[i] != ' ') print s[i]; `
```

Now address is never space, hence your if block will always be true.
But as you want to check for s to be printed without spaces check for values: 
      `if( s[i] != ' ' ) print s [i];`

Also, as you are comparing charecter wise, you should understand that, " " is for string and for characters you should use single quotes  ' '.