# Why do 'char' values have to have single quotation marks instead of double?

Tags: c++, char

**Goal**

At the end, I want to know why C++ doesn't support `char letter = "C";` but does support `char letter = 'C';` (notice that the quotation marks are different).

**Code**

I am using Repl.it as a code platform.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char letter = "C";
    std::cout << letter;
}
```

**Error message**

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:5:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
     char letter = "C";

Comment: Because that's the syntax. Not much more to it than that...

Comment: Do you understand why C++ doesn't allow `int i = {1,2,3,4,5};`? It is kind of the same principle.

Comment: One can always create his own programming language. I guess it works for a master's degree... At least the beginning to it at least.

Comment: "C" is a string. It is zero terminated and is stored in memory. When assigning it gives the address. 'C' is a single byte that is just copied to the variable.

Comment: Because the standard says so: [lex.ccon](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#1)

Comment: Two different things. One is a *string of characters* ("lots of letters"), the other is a *single character* ('A'). So *double quotes* can contain many characters whereas *single quotes* can only contain (logically) one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are needed because `'C'` and `"C"` represent completely different types - the first is an integer value, while the second is an array of two characters (the letter `'C'`  plus an implicit null-terminator). Both are useful, and you need some way of saying  which one you want, which is what the different kinds of quotes do.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are for single characters whereas double quotes are used to create string literals. They mean different things.

See a [more thorough explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: There are things like _multibyte character literals_ in c++. Rarely used, but available.