# const char* vs char for array (single and double quotation) in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++

1)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char arr[4];
    arr[0] = 'H';
    arr[1] = 'e';
    arr[2] = 'l';
    arr[3] = 'o';
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");

}
```

2)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char* arr[4];
    arr[0] = "H";
    arr[1] = "e";
    arr[2] = "l";
    arr[3] = "o";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

If I use `""` for `char[]` array, or `''` for `const char*[]` array, it doesn't work.

Could somebody help me figure out the difference why it happens, and explain what `const char*` actually means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Sidenote: this is actually undefined behavior--you need a [terminating null character](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-is-a-null-terminated-string)!

Comment: Unlike some languages, in C and C++ there's a *huge difference* between `'a'` and `"a"`.

Comment: Worthwhile warning, but disagree with UB. Asker is not using the array as a string and doesn't need the nul terminator in their example.

Comment: @scohe001 Which terminating null are you referring to?

Comment: If I was new to C++, I would start by trying `std::string s = "Hello";`. C style arrays are difficult, *especially* `char` arrays. Save that for later.

Comment: @KillzoneKid C-strings must be null-terminated. In the first example if he tries to pass `arr` to a function and it decays to a pointer, he's going to be in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if i use "" for char array or '' for const char* array it doesn't
>   work

In the first example you create an array of 4 `chars` - `char arr[4];` This means that every element of `arr` is a `char`. `'H'` is a `char`, `'e'` is a `char`, etc. So when you assign a `char` to array element that is a `char`, it works.

In your second example you create array of 4 pointers to `const char` - `const char* arr[4];` This means every element of your array is a pointer, and it points to `char` which you promise not to change. `"H"` is a string literal, which is an array of 2 - a `char` `'H'` and a terminating null `'\0'`. This array decays into a pointer to its first element, which is `'H'` - a `const char` (same for the rest of letters). Your array is array of pointers to `const char`, you assign pointer to `const char`, so it works.

If you swap `''` with `""` it will not work because the types of array elements will not match with data you will be assigning.