# Printing type-cast types in C

Tags: c, types, printf, typecasting-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int nr = 5;
  char castChar = (char)nr;
  char realChar = '5';
  printf("The value is: %d\n", castChar);
}
```

If the above code is compiled, the output will be:

```
The value is: 5
```

But if the code below is compiled, the console will output the value 53 instead. Why doesn't it print the same as the when the "castChar" is printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int nr = 5;
  char castChar = (char)nr;
  char realChar = '5';
  printf("The value is: %d\n", realChar);
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: because the ASCII value of the string '5' is 53.  If you want to print it as a string then use %c

Comment: I know what ASCII is and how printf works. Take a look at the code again, the castChar is a type-casted char. And it prints 5, that is the translated value from ASCII. The realChar is initialized to a char, and not type-casted as castChar. Both are chars but they print out different values.

Comment: @OldProgrammer You cannot assume ASCII character set

Comment: `(char)5` and `'5'` mean completely different things.

Comment: @user2357112 could you please explain how they are different? From my understanding, a type conversion is basically a change of how the data is stored in the memory.

Comment: @OldProgrammer `'5'` is not string, it's character. String comes in `" "` double quote in C. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683613/7508077

Comment: C is not an object-oriented language and casting != conversion.

Comment: Link explain difference between casting and conversion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133078/325759

Answer (score 3):

Because the value of `castChar` is the integer value `5`, while the value of `realChar` is the *integer encoding of the character value* `'5'` (ASCII 53).  These are not the same values.

Casting has nothing to do with it.  Or, more accurately, casting `nr` to `char` doesn't give you the *character value* `'5'`, it just assigns the integer value `5` to a narrower type.

If you expect the output `5`, then you need to print `realChar` with the `%c` specifier, not the `%d` specifier.

Comment: i hear in C we can use other character set instead of ASCII, is it possible that `realChar` in the `char realChar = '5';` have different value than 53?

Comment: Does that mean that the maximum value of casted ints differs from non-casted ints?

Comment: @EsmaeelE: C leaves it up to the underlying platform - as long as the basic character set is supported and encodings for decimal digits are contiguous, it doesn't really care whether the underlying representation is ASCII or EBCDIC or whatever.

Comment: @MoonOnAStick: Not quite sure what you mean by that.  If you try to cast an integer value to a *signed* integer type that's too small to hold it (for example, `signed char x = (signed char) 12345;`), you'll get an implementation-defined result (or a trap).  If you try to cast an integer value to an *unsigned* type that's too small, you'll get the modulus.

Comment: Is is true?    If the system coding is EBCDIC, `char realChar = '5'` put in `realChar`,  `hF5: 11110101` the decimal equivalent 20.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: Decimal equivalent 245, but yes, it will be a different value from the ASCII code for `'5'`.

Comment: _"i hear in C we can use other character set instead of ASCII"_ - You cannot arbitrarily choose the character set or encoding - that is platform specific not something you can select in the language.  On modern platforms you generally have a choice between ASCII/ANSI and Unicode in the _execution environment_, but it is complicated because Unicode does not define a single encoding and there are several variable width encodings.

Comment: Talk of EBCDIC is largely relevant - you cannot choose to use it if the platform does not use it and platforms that do are obsolete - its encoding is designed to be convenient for use on punched cards.  Which makes it inconvenient for almost any other purpose.

Comment: @Clifford _On modern platforms you generally have a choice between ASCII/ANSI_, How i can choose between them? And why we do this selections? what is application of that things? Is it possible to code on a machine with ASCII coding like my current PC and develop an application that must run on other coding like ANSI?

Comment: @EsmaeelE: You don’t make that choice.  It’s whatever comes with the platform.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: It is possible to write code that is designed to work correctly regardless of the source or execution character set.

Comment: @EsmaeelE ; SO is not a discussion forum; you should not ask further questions in comments - especially comments against an answer where the question is unrelated. Unicode supports thousands of code-points and thus supports Kanji, Catacana, Hebrew, Cyrilic, European accented characters etc. - even Egyptian hieroglyphs!  With 8 bit character sets, you are limited to languages with small alphabets and the use of locale specific code-pages. C itself does not have direct support for Unicode or code-pages - its is a platform issue.  
 Research first: https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`(char)5` and `'5'` are not the same thing.

The literal `'5'` is an integer value that represents the character 5. Its value depends on the platform. Assuming ASCII representation for characters, this would be 53.

The literal `(char)5` is the integer value 5 that has been cast to type `char`. This means it retains the value of 5 after the cast.

Comment: What's the point of type-casting if it doesn't behave as the type casted?

Comment: Casts should generally be avoided. There is almost always a way to write code that uses a type cast into cleaner code that does not use it. Type-casting in C would be used to reinterpret a type as a different type, such as a signed integer as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Strict aliasing requires an object to only be interpreted by its own type or as `char`. So, you will sometimes see an object pointer be treated as a `char *`, and sometimes this will be done via a cast.

Comment: @MoonOnAStick: it *does* behave like the type casted - if necessary, the value being cast will be converted to a different representation.  It will not change the *value*, though.  Again, the integer value `5` and the character value `'5'` are not the same, and a simple cast won't convert one to the other.

Comment: Another case where a cast is required is to make sure a pointer is passed into a variable argument function that expects to see a NULL pointer. Since `NULL` may be defined as a bare `0`, it would be passed as an `int` without a cast.