# comparing a char in a dynamic array with a char

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, types, casting

I want to print a dynamic char array which has \0 characters before the actual end.
I am printing it by using `cout` for every index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        std::cout << content[i];
}
```

But when I come by a \0 character I want to detect it, so I'm using:

```
if (content[i] == 0) {
     std::cout "zero";
}
```

I tried to do

```
if (content[i] == "\0") {
     std::cout "zero";
}
```

But I can't do that comparison because you apparently cannot compare a `const char*` and a `char`.

What did I do wrong? How do I make this comparison?

`char` array btw:

```
char * content = new char[size];
file.seekg(0);
file.read(content, size);
```

Comment: `content[i] == 0` compares a `char` and an `int`. What specifically is giving you said error?

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please! ([Edit] your question)

Comment: `content[i] == 0` is correct, so whatever problem you are having, it's not that. There's some other issue with your code and you're only making things worse by trying to fix the wrong thing (common newbie situation). Posting a complete program illustrating your problem instead of just snippetts would help.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c) helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in

```
if (content[i] == "\0")
```

the `"\0"` is a string literal, a `const char [2]` in this case. This [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer, resulting in a `const char *` being compared with a `char` and the compiler error.

You want

```
if (content[i] == '\0')
```

to get a null as a character. That said, integers can compare against `char`, so `if (content[i] == 0)` is valid, but (my opinion) less clear than explicitly making a null character.

Further reading: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c) ([chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) provided the link)

Answer (score -4):

Try `"0"` in you if-statement, since then you would be comparing the same types

Comment: \0 is not the same as "0".

Comment: Raw `char*` pointers aren't really compared like this. OP would need to use `strcmp()` to do that.