# What am I doing wrong here with find and string?

Tags: c++, string, find

I am asking user to enter date in format with slashes. Then I try to find the slashes in the string using find. I get error saying I cannot compare pointer with integer on my if statement. Here is code.

```
// test inputing string date formats
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   std::string dateString;
   int month,day,year;

   std::cout << "Enter a date in format of 5/14/1999: ";
   std::getline(std::cin,dateString);

   std::cout << "You entered " << dateString << std::endl;

   if (std::find(dateString.begin(),dateString.end(),"/") != dateString.end()) {
      std::cout << "Found slash in date.\n";
   }
   else {
      std::cout << "screwed it up.\n";
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but isn’t / a special character? Try //

Comment: @MikhailGenkin it's nothing special.  *back-slash* is what you're thinking of.

Comment: If I were to point you to [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c), would you see that as a duplicate question?

Comment: You should be looking for a value of element-type, where the type is decided from the iterators used. A `std::string` contains `char`. You're providing a `const char*` (eventually). They're not synonymous. Look for `'/'` , not `"/"` .

Comment: @WhozCraig and that should not be the answer?

Comment: @WhozCraig so, better to close as a typo

Comment: Unrelated: "`5/14/1999`" isn't a format. It's a point in time or an example of a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (std::find(dateString.begin(),dateString.end(),"/") != dateString.end()) {
```

`"/"` is a literal string, or a `const char *` (actually a `const char[2]` in this case, to be pedantic, but this is not germane) . The third parameter to `std::find`, in this case, should be a `char`, a single character.

You probably meant

```
if (std::find(dateString.begin(),dateString.end(),'/') != dateString.end()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```cpp
if (dateString.find("/") != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Found slash in date.\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "screwed it up.\n";
}
```

to find substring/char in a string. Note that [std::string::find()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) works for  char, const char * and std::string.