# C++ Character array element based on index no comparison

Tags: c++

I'm attempting a logical comparison at an element in a char-array based on index number but my compiler says illegal comparison. Any ideas about what's going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream MyFile("Assignmentfile.txt");
int userno;
char name[16];
char lastname[16];
char address[51];
char cellno[14];
char landlineno[12];
int sent;

void userinput();
void searchfunc();
void deletecontact();
void displaycontact();
void modifycontact();
void sortcontact();
void findcontact();

int main()
{
    MyFile<<"First Name   Last Name   Address   Cell Number   Landline Number"<<endl;       
    userinput();        
    return 0;
}

void userinput()
{
    {   
        cout<<"Would you like to enter a new contact? (1/0) ";
        cin>>sent;
        while (sent==1)
        {
            cout<<"Enter Name: ";
            cin>>name;
            MyFile<<left<<setw(16)<<name<<"|";
            cout<<"Enter Last name: ";
            cin>>lastname;
            MyFile<<left<<setw(16)<<lastname<<"|";
            cout<<"Enter Address: ";
            cin>>address;
            MyFile<<left<<setw(51)<<address<<"|";
            cout<<"Enter Cell Number: ";
            cin>>cellno;
            if (cellno[0]=="+")
            {
                cout<<"Enter Cell number again starting with +92"; // The problem appears here //
            }
            MyFile<<left<<setw(14)<<cellno<<"|";
            cout<<"Enter Landline Number: ";
            cin>>landlineno;
            MyFile<<left<<setw(12)<<landlineno<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Would you like to enter a new contact? (1/0) ";
            cin>>sent;

        }
        MyFile.close();
    }
}
```

The program must be able to write and read from a text file. It can create contacts, modify them, delete them, sort them and search through them. The problem is that the cell number must start from `"+92"` i.e `"+923454356568"`. I thought that `if (cellno[0]=="+")` and so on would work.

I cannot use strings and only have to rely on character type arrays. Using strings would make all of this a piece of cake.

Below is the assignment I wish to complete.

[image]

Comment: Provide a minimal (one more  a minimal) complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `if (cellno[0]=="+")` won't work, but did you try `if (cellno[0]=='+')` ?

Comment: @Romen ill try.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this is the complete program

Comment: @HassanIftikhar That should be "complete" in the sense of "fully compiles while demonstrating the error", not in the sense of "does everything my assignment requires". The goal is **minimal** and *complete*: all the code needed to demonstrate the problem, but no more than needed (c.f. [mcve]). If asked well, this question should have no need to include your full assignment description.

Comment: Also the file is cleaned blank each time i run the program. I would like the data entered into the file to stay. How do i do that?

Comment: @JaMiT This is my first semester and first ever experience at coding. Not to sound rude or anything i came here for help on my code not a lesson on how to carry out things. I posted the whole assignment to be safe and so that it is easy for people to understand why i'm doing what i'm asking and what is the basic functionality of the program. If I didn't mention I can't use strings people would say "just use a string instead of char".

Comment: You have a problem. Create a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Your example is not minimal. Read [mcve]

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm very new to programming and i'm sorry if this is all confusing but i literally have no idea about a lot of stuff. If you mean that i only post a program that deals with the character array and its functionality alone i'll post that.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Alright thanks

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite or truncate the old file you have to open it with the corresponding flag [app](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream

Comment: @HassanIftikhar As I understand it, you came here for help on your code, not help on getting help on your code. You have no interest in having your experience help others. You also believe that if someone asks you to make it easier for them to help you, then that is unfairly shifting a burden from them (the volunteer) to you (the only one who will benefit). Kind of short-sighted and self-centered, but I guess it worked out this time. Since someone had the time to sort through your code, I was able to find a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
if (cellno[0]=="+")
```

You are comparing single character, at index 0 in `cellno` char array (which hopefully contains a C string) with *string literal*, which is a pointer (as your compler error says).

You want to compare a single char, like this:

```
if (cellno[0]=='+')
```

Note how single and double quotes have a very different meaning!

---

You code has a lot of other issues, too many to list here, but that should solve the problem you are asking about. But one advice I add: do not use C strings in C++, if you can avoid it! Use `std::string` as soon as you are allowed to!

Comment: Tysm. Tbh you are the only person here who's not triggered and isn't scolding me for posting the whole thing and assuming that I should naturally just know the solution to this problem. This fixes it and solves my problem for now. Thank you!

Comment: Just to add a few suggestions to your code in general. Do not use global variables if they are not necessary, use getline for getting a line of text from user input (for  example to get the address which will probably have multiple words). Why the additional {} scope inside of the userinput function?

Comment: @HassanIftikhar: don't take the feedback personally. When you posted here, it looked like you wanted someone to do your work for you, which usually is not well received. Readers also saw that you wanted volunteers here to be affected by your deadline (which I have now removed). In the circumstances, some critical feedback is to be expected.