# char assignment in C

Tags: c

Why does this generate errors?

```
char variable = "\n"; 
printf ("%c",variable);
```

But changing the double quotes to single  fixes it?

```
char variable = '\n';
printf ("%c",variable);
```

Comment: A string (the 1st example) is null terminated.  so requires two characters. Heed your compiler's warnings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `"\n"` is an array of chars. Specifically a `char[2]` array, as it is the same as `{'\n',0}`. And you cannot assign a `char[2]` to a `char`.

Even without the null termination you would still not be able to assign it because of the type mismatch. No `char[N]` (for a fixed `N`) can be assigned to a `char`.