# single vs double quotes C++ - interesting, unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, c-str

I found some pretty weird behaviour when I was trying to debug my C++ code for an unrelated problem.

I am printing a result at a stage in the program at which I have the integer variables 'amount' and 'coins[i]' as:

```
std::cout << "Found, 1! n = " <<  amount/coins[i] << " * " << coins[i] << "\n";
```

However, it makes a difference whether I place the * in double or single quotes. For double quotes, meaning the * is a string, we get:

```
Found, 1! n = 11 * 1
```

But for singles we get:

```
Found, 1! n = 1121079361
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Please provide the code that produces second output as [mcve].

Comment: See item 6 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

Comment: FYI, GCC and Clang [warn about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hn6od4) and give you a search term.

Comment: The behavior is  implementation-defined [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684046/14170464)