# How to insert data into an array of single structure data type

Tags: c++

Im trying to put data into an array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct table {
    int number;
    double  rate, hour;
    string name;
} test[5];

int main()
{
    test[0]={2,0.0,1.1,'m'};
    test[1]={2,0.0,1.1,'m'};
   
   return 0;
}
```

I know the syntax is wrong for this  `test[0]={2,0.0,1.1,'m'};`. please correct it.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c

Comment: no. non of this answers my question

Comment: @The That's because you're asking the wrong question. Fix 1st things 1st, before trying anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong type of quotes: `'m'` is a `char` but you need a `std::string`.  Change it to `"m"` and your code compiles.