# Difference between using " and ' in C

Tags: c, char, warnings, implicit-conversion, string-literals

I tried running a C program with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char grade;
    float mark;
    printf("Enter total mark percentage : ");
    scanf("%f", &mark);
    if(mark>=90){
        grade="A";
    }else{
        grade="B";
    }
    printf("Your grade is %c", grade);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It produces a warning 'assignment from 'char' to 'char*' makes integer from pointer without a cast'.
I am able to solve it by changing **"** to **'** in line 10 and 12

```
        grade='A';
    }else{
        grade='B';
    }
```

This solves the warning. But I want to use " to contain A & B.
I tried initializing *mark*, as **int** instead of **char** in line 5 but it also didn't work.
I just want to know what is the difference in using **'** and **"** .

Comment: Single quote is used for `char` type while double quote for string literals. `grade="A";` is an ill formed code. `grade` expects a `char` data type while you are assigning `"A"` which is of string literal type.

Comment: This question is a tad basic, you probably should not explore the entire language like this, it could save time all around if you read a book about the language. [Here's a random list of books of varying quality.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: You could try to read a beginner-level C book and the answer will be revealed in the string chapter.

Comment: "_I want to use " to contain A & B_" - why?  Change `char grade;` to `const char* grade;` and the format specifier from `%c` to `%s` and you can.  But there is no reason in the world to do so unless you want to assign grades such as `"B+"` or `"A*"` perhaps.  I'd post that as an answer, but your question was _"I just want to know what is the difference in using ' and ""_ rather than _"how can I do what I want?"_.  Maybe it is an X-Y problem?  You could ask the question you really want to know the answer to and it would be less likely to be a duplicate and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `'` is used to specify an integer character constant. For example `'A'` is an integer character constant that has the type `int`.

The symbol `"` is used to specify a string literal. For example `"A"` is a string literal that has the type `char[2]`. That is the string literal is a character array that is stored like

```
{ 'A', '\0' }
```

String literals contain sequences of characters terminated by the zero terminating  character `'\0'` that also is stored in string literals.

Character arrays designators used in expressions are implicitly (with rare exceptions) converted to pointers to their first elements of the type `char *` or `const char *`.

This means that in this assignment statement

```
grade="A";
```

the string literal `"A"` that has the array type `char[2]` is converted to a pointer to its first element `'A'`. As a result the compiler issues a message that you are trying to assign a pointer to an object of an integer type.

You can write for example

```
grade = "A"[0];
```

or

```
grade = *"A";
```

But this will only confuse readers of the code because it will be more simpler and clear to write

```
grade = 'A';
```

That is there is no need to use a whole array like `"A"` (remember that it  internally represents an array of two elements `{ 'A', '\0' }`) to use only its one element `'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

"..." is used for strings - ie. a NUL-terminated char-array (char[] or char*)

'.' is used for a *single* character - ie. a char.

For example:
"Hello" is a string (char-array) with the following 6 single characters:

'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' (The last is the NUL-character).

Thus

'A' is just 'A' (a single char containing the ASCII-value for A)

while

"A" is a char *array*, containing two chars - 'A' and '\0' (and thus a string)

Answer (score 0):

" " are used for string and  ' ' is used for the character. as A and B are
characters we will use single quotes for them.

this is why this format is correct.

```
grade='A';
    }else{
        grade='B';
    }
```