# difference between declaring char variable with '' or "" in c

Tags: c, char, declaration, string-literals, multibyte-characters

**what is the difference between**

```
char name='chiheb';

char name="chiheb";
```

I'm also confused about how char can allow many characters .what is the difference then between string and char;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Comment: Single quote is for char. Double quotes are fir character pointers (pointers to strings of characters)

Comment: A **string** is an *array* of `char` with a NUL terminator. Some C libraries do define a `string` type (which isn't an array but a pointer), and that is often considered to be unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the first declaration on object of the type `char` is initialized by a multi-byte integer character constant the value of which is implementation defined.

For the second declaration the compiler will issue a message that you are trying to convert a pointer to an integer because the string literal used as an initializer is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

A valid declaration will look like for example

```
char name = "chiheb"[0]; // or some other used valid index
```

or

```
char name = *"chiheb";
```

or

```
char *name = "chiheb";
```

Comment: i didnt understand this part : In the first declaration on object of the type char is initialized by a multibyte integer character constant the value of which is implementation defined.

Comment: @chihebnouri  The value of this multibyte integer character constant 'chiheb' is implementation defined. So you can not say apriore  how the variable  name will be initialized.