# Unable to intialise string by using double quotes in C

Tags: c, string, struct

Where

```
char member[50];
```

Inside

```
Struct structure_variable
```

Why am I unable to initialise `structure_variable.member='Dev';` in C?

Comment: Related: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3683602/1275169)

Comment: 1. That's not intialisation. Initialisation occurs at the point you define the (struct) variable. So you can initialise with a string but you can't assign a string. Why? That's how the language is defined. Use `strcpy` in that latter case. 2. `'Dev'` should be `"Dev"` if you want it to be a string.

Comment: Please post the actual code, using code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an *assignment*, not an *initialization*.

The correct way for assigning a *null-terminated char array* (a string) is using `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(structure_variable.member, "Dev");
```

meaning that you copy all the characters of the string `"Dev"` (included the string terminator `'\0'` at the end) in the memory location starting from the `char` pointer `member`.

Note: I assumed that the use of `'Dev'` in your question is a typo, as strings need to be enclosed by double quotes as you correctly stated in your question.