# C++: wchar_t cannot be stored in a std::map as a key or value

Tags: c++, char, stdmap, wchar-t

I am trying to make a variable with the data type `std::map<char, wchar_t>` in C++. When I try this, Visual Studio gives this build error:

> C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::map<char,wchar_t,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<const char,wchar_t>>>'

The same error also occurs when `wchar_t` is the key data type and `char` is the value data type.

You can replicate this error by running the following code:

```
const std::map<char, wchar_t> UNICODE_MAP = {
    { 'X', L"█" },
    { 'G', L"▓" },
    { 'O', L"ᗣ" },
    { 'P', L"ᗤ" }
};
```

How would I make a map with the key as a `char` and the value as a `wchar_t` data type?

Comment: FAQ: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c) applies to wide character types as well as narrow characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a map from narrow char to wide char, not char to wide string:

Instead of this:

```
const std::map<char, wchar_t> UNICODE_MAP = {
    { 'X', L"█" },
    { 'G', L"▓" },
    { 'O', L"ᗣ" },
    { 'P', L"ᗤ" }
};
```

Use this:

```
const std::map<char, wchar_t> UNICODE_MAP = {
    { 'X', L'█' },
    { 'G', L'▓' },
    { 'O', L'ᗣ' },
    { 'P', L'ᗤ' }
};
```

If you actually need the value to be a string, then declare it as:

```
const std::map<char, std::wstring> UNICODE_MAP = {
    { 'X', L"█" },
    ...
```

Also, while I'm here, I advocate for escaping all Unicode chars in source files that are not in the ASCII range.  Between IDEs with varying behaviors, revision control systems, and the guy down the hall who didn't read your memo about "save as Unicode", this can get easily corrupted.  So... my final recommendation is this:

```
const std::map<char, wchar_t> UNICODE_MAP = {
    { 'X', L'\u2588' },
    { 'G', L'\u2593' },
    { 'O', L'\u15e3' },
    { 'P', L'\u15e4' }
};
```