# error in finding no. of vowels in a string

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

```
//schecking no of vowels in a string.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printstring();

int main() {

    char sai[8];           //allows 8 charecters. 
    char a,e,j,o,u;        //I have used j as i have already used i for iteration
    fgets(sai, 8, stdin);  //going to enter my name
    char *ptr = sai;       ///setting pointer for string
    int i,t = 0;

    for(i = 0;i <= 7; i++){
        if(*(ptr+i) == a) || (*(ptr+i) == e) || (*(ptr+i) == j) || (*(ptr + i) == o) || (*(ptr + i) == u){
            t = t+1;
        }

        else {
            t = t;
        }
}
printf("%d", t);
}
```

### OUTPUT:

The compiler generated an error:

```
jill.c: In function 'main':
jill.c:12:23: error: expected expression before '||' token
     if(*(ptr+i) == a) || (*(ptr+i) == e) || (*(ptr+i) == j) || (*(ptr + i) == o) || (*(ptr + i) == u){
                       ^~
```

I expected the number of vowels as output, but an error has occured. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do yourself and anyone reading your question a favor and apply some proper indentation. That code is barely readable. You will read your own code more often than you write it.

Comment: Count parentheses here: `if(*(ptr+i) == a)`

Comment: Fwiw: `*(ptr+i) == a` is easier to read if you write it like this: `ptr[i] == a`

Comment: `char a,e,j,o,u;` are _unitialized_. Better to change (e.g.) `(*(ptr+i) == a)` into `(ptr[i] == 'a')`

Answer (score 1):

Below listed points are incorrect in your code

1. Englobe the full condition between brackets in your if condition is missing
2. Single quotes are missing for character in your if statements. [please go through here more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c).
3. As comment from  Ted Lyngmo, Craig Estey   a,e,j,o,u are uninitialized.

`if (*(ptr + i) == a) ||(*(ptr + i) == e) || (*(ptr + i) == j) || (*(ptr + i) == o) || (*(ptr + i) == u)`

changed to

```
if((ptr[i] == 'a') || (ptr[i] == 'e') || (ptr[i] == 'j') || (ptr[i] == 'o') || (ptr[i] == 'u'))
```

code

```
//schecking no of vowels in a string.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void printstring();
int main()
{
    char sai[8];//allows 8 charecters. 
    char a,e,j,o,u; //I have used j as i have already used i for iteration
    fgets(sai, 8, stdin);  //going to enter my name
    char *ptr = sai; ///setting pointer for string
    int i,t = 0;
    for(i = 0;i <= 7; i++)
    {
        if((ptr[i] == 'a') || 
           (ptr[i] == 'e') || 
           (ptr[i] == 'j') || 
           (ptr[i] == 'o') || 
           (ptr[i] == 'u'))
           {
                t = t+1;
           }
        else
        {
            t = t;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", t);
  }
```

[Link for below Output](https://onlinegdb.com/hmlKRn0d8):

```
apple
2
```