# Why do I keep getting this "excess elements in char array initializer" error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool esittir(char char_array[],int size,string str_array)
{
    if(size != str_array.length())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(char_array[i] != str_array[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

void print(string names[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length(); j++)
            cout << names[i][j] << " , ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    string Names [] = {"Evrim","Can","Bayhan"};
    string ilk_isim = "Evrim";
    char charversiyonu[] = {"E","v","r","i","m"};
    print(Names,3);
    cout << esittir(charversiyonu,5,ilk_isim) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to convert the char array to a pointer, but this time too the above control mechanism gave an error due to inequality due to not being able to compare an array with a pointer.

What should I do? I'm a beginner to C++.

Comment: `'E'` is a single `char`. `"E"` is a `char` array (a string).

Comment: "cannot compare an array with a pointer" — is it an error or a warning? Also, the compiler prints the line number. Which line does the error belong to? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: "*What should I do? I'm a beginner to C++*" - you should get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from.

Comment: Do you know the difference in using the double quote (`"E"`) and single quote (`'E'`) in C++?  I know that in other languages it may not make a difference, but in C++ it makes a huge difference.

Comment: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:
Just change

```
char charversiyonu[] = {"E","v","r","i","m"};
```

To

```
char charversiyonu[] = {'E','v','r','i','m'};
```

As for the why:
the double quote ["] creates a string literal, which is basically a glorified char array with some caveats. So even if you do `"a"` that means it is a char array with two elements. The `a` character and the `\0` character to terminate the string.
So by doing this:

```
char charversiyonu[] = {"E","v","r","i","m"};
```

Because you are using double quotes instead of single quotes, you are telling the compiler to create an array of 5 char arrays ("arrays in an array") and not an array of 5 chars.

By changing to single quotes ['] you are indeed telling the compiler to create an array of chars as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
char charversiyonu[] = {"E","v","r","i","m"};
```

You're declaring an array of characters, but you are populating it with strings.  `"E"` is a C string literal.  `'E'` is a C character literal, and that's what you want instead.